# Avoid double encoding json

Tags: python, json, pandas

I'm trying to wrap a pandas dataframe in another json response. You can see below that I use to_json() to create job.result. But when I wrap it with other json items it either does not serialize because it is a dict, or encodes the pandas object twice. How can I wrap the pandas item with other json items without double encoding? I considered using to_dict() instead of to_json(), but then I run into date format issues.

```
job.result = result.to_json(date_format='iso')

data = {
    'status': job.get_status(),
    'result': job.result,
}
response = make_response(data)
response.mimetype = 'application/json'
return response
```

Comment: What does `make_response` return, and how can you access its payload?

Comment: Sorry. make_response is imported from flask and enables me to return a regular string as json. It's the same as flask's jsonify.

Comment: Can you explain this?: "_But when I wrap it with other json items it either does not serialize because it is a dict,_" Dicts are serialisable... Also, when you say encoding, what do you mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Doing some [quick research](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_json.html) on pandas to_json, that function returns a string representation of your json object, not the actual json object.

If your intent is to send it as part of the actual object instead of just a string, I would parse it before sending it, aka, the equivalent of: `job.result = JSON.parse(result.to_json(date_format='iso'))`.

**Edit:** because I kind of answered in the context of javascript instead of python, `json.loads(result.to_json(date_format='iso'))` is the Python solution the OP ended up using.

Comment: Yes I understand it returns a string. I guess my question is how can I convert the rest what's in the data variable into a string? Do you think that would be easier than parsing it?

Comment: I guess it depends on what you want the final representation to be - should `data.result` on the client side give a string representation of json, or the json itself?

Comment: If you just want to surround it with a json-representative string though, there's always the option of just doing, `data = '{\'status\':' + job.get_status() + ', \'result\':' + job.result + '}'`, which would give the client the raw json object, or just inserting a set of \'s around job.result to keep it a string.

Comment: Actually your method was right! I used json.loads(result.to_json(date_format='iso')) and it formatted nicely within the data object. Thank you!